# why hash the hashcode in java hashmap?

Tags: java

when I see java hashMap source code,I see the code like this.

```
public V put(K key, V value) {
    if (key == null)
        return putForNullKey(value);
    int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
    int i = indexFor(hash, table.length);
    for (Entry<K,V> e = table[i]; e != null; e = e.next) {
        Object k;
        if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k))) {
            V oldValue = e.value;
            e.value = value;
            e.recordAccess(this);
            return oldValue;
        }
    }
    modCount++;
    addEntry(hash, key, value, i);
    return null;
}
```

So I don't know why we should hash the hashcode,is there some problem with hashcode?  thinks.

Comment: To protect against bad hashCode implementations.